# String length after replacing a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace, string-length, replaceall

How can I get the correct length of the new string after replacing a substring in the string. I used the string length and got the length of 1st string.
ie.
My string is "abcdefg" and length is 7. After replacing "cde" with "z", the new string is abzfg ( by using replace all) and the length of new string is still 7, if I use string length. Can I get the correct length 5 by any method?

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String are immutable in Java. You can't change them.

You will need to use another String or use StringBuilder.

```
String A = "abcdefg";
String B = A.substring(0,2) + 'z' + A.substring(5,6);
```

Or With StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder A = new StringBuilder("abcdefg");
A.replace(2,5,"z");
```

Answer (score 2):

Save your new string in a new variable. And then check length.

```
String s = a.replace(...);
int newLength = s.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java strings are immutable. http://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/why-string-is-immutable-in-java/

Meaning you have to persist the result of a replace operation on a string object. (Functions don't directly modify the actual content of the string object)

Example: You can do something like this in your case

```
string s = "abcdefg";
s = s.replace("cde", "");
System.out.println(s.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the Code for the above question and it is producing the correct output,

i.e 5. Make sure that you have written :-

```
 str=str.replaceAll("cde","z");
```

and not just

```
str.replaceAll("cde","z");
```

(Because the String class in Java is immutable)